# Contradiction and proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics

the problem is verify this statement:  $$\lnot ( \lnot p \land q)^\land (p \lor q)=p$$

That turns into $p \lor ( \lnot q \land  q)$ - which that last part of the statement is a contradiction and is always false

which means now I have $p \lor F =p$

Does that mean that the original statement is true and valid or does it mean it's false? Could someone please explain.

Comment: It means that the equivalence does indeed hold, since you have shown that you can convert $\neg(\neg p \land q) \land (p \lor q)$ into $p$ through the application of elementary equivalence principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the task is to determine whether $$\lnot( \lnot p \land q)\land (p \lor q) \equiv p \tag{Q}$$

We'll start on the left-hand side (LHS) and use equivalencies to prove that $(Q)$ is true:

$$\begin{align} \lnot( \lnot p \land q)\land (p \lor q) &\equiv (p \lor \lnot q)\land (p \lor q)\tag{De Morgan's} \\ \\
&\equiv p \lor (\underbrace{\lnot q \land q}_{\text{False}})\tag{distributive property} \\ \\
&\equiv p \lor \text {False}\\ \\
&\equiv p \end{align}$$

This means that $$\lnot( \lnot p \land q)\land (p \lor q) \equiv  p\tag{Q}$$ ***is true***, since we've shown that the left hand side of $(Q)$ is equivalent to the right hand side, hence the equivalence is true.

Comment: does ⊥ mean a contradiction or a tautology? contradiction right? So p ∨ contradiction always just equals p?

Comment: It means that $\lnot q \land q$ is always false. (Yes, $p \lor \text {contradiction} \equiv p$, always.   Remember in a disjunction, which is what we have, $p \lor \bot \equiv p$.  However, if we had had a conjunction at the end, of the form $p \land \bot $, then we would end with $p\land \bot \equiv \bot.$

Comment: That explains a lot thank you. If you don't mind and have time could you type out what you just typed out in the comment above but with tautology's?

Comment: $p \lor \top \equiv \top$, where $\top$ is a tautology.  For example, $p \lor (q \lor \lnot q) \equiv p \lor \top \equiv \top.$  Suppose we have $p \land (q \lor \lnot q)$.  Then we have $p \land \top \equiv p$.

Comment: So you're saying that if we end up p ∨ ⊤=p ... then the statement does not equal p? but if we end up with p ^ T=p ... then the statement does equal p?

Comment: That's correct:  For disjunction ($\lor$), we have $p \lor F = p$, $p \lor T = T$.  For conjunction, ($\land$), we have $p \land F = F$, $p\land T = p$

Comment: Does that help, @LittleAuditorium ?

Comment: Yeah that gives me a much better understanding from before asking this question and your posts. Thank you for helping me out it helped a ton @amWhy